# Linq: Convert datatable rows to Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: linq

I have a data table with columns "a", "b", "c". a and b are my lookup keys, and so I want to find c.

I'd like to use linq to convert it to a `Dictionary<a, Dictionary<b, c>>` (or an ILookup)

Is this possible?

The closet workaround I can come up with is:

```
var lookup = resultTable.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(row => row["a"] & row["b"], 
                                               row => row["c"]);
```

and then I can concatenate a+b to use as the key.

Is there a better way, or is this possibly faster anyways due to it being a simpler data structure?

Comment: You must be a VB guy huh?  :)

Comment: Ha, yeah I was doing VB right before typing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it in C#:

```
var dict = resultTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<A>("a"))
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.ToDictionary(
            row => row.Field<B>("b"),
            row => row.Field<C>("c")
        )
    );
```

And equivalent VB:

```
Dim dict = resultTable.AsEnumerable               
    .GroupBy(Function(row) row.Field(Of A)("a"))  
    .ToDictionary(                               
        Function(g) g.Key,                       
        Function(g) g.ToDictionary(              
            Function(row) row.Field(Of B)("b"),  
            Function(row) row.Field(Of C)("c")   
        )                                        
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I think you should strive for a `Dictionary<Tuple<A, B>, C>`:

```
var dict = resultTable.AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(row => Tuple.Create(
                                          row.Field<A>("a"), 
                                          row.Field<B>("b")
                                      )
                      )
                      .ToDictionary(
                          group => group.Key,
                          group => group.Single().Field<C>("c")
                      );
```

Comment: While I agree, C# doesn't make using it any easier.  In its "raw" form, using it is very awkward.  It becomes more bearable supplemented with supporting extension methods or derived types.  If only there was a real tuple syntax in the language...